# What's so downvotable about this question?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72752/45856) is short and to the point. Did I not show off how much I know enough? Why the drive-by *do you even know what you are talking about?* comment?

In most SE sites clear, concise questions are welcome. How could I have written this question differently to have avoided being asked "[So have you watched all three movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72752/#comment117932_72752)" When asking questions about series' of films, is it necessary state "I have seen all of them"?

This kind of drive-by *maybe you are not smart enough to be asking questions here* comment is common in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) and I understand that old habits are hard to unlearn, but most of the less frantic sites are generally accepting to a wide range of questions and "skill levels". What ever happened to "be nice"?

When one has low rep in a new site, the silent downvotes without helpful comments just sting. This is not productive. Besides I just plopped a fifty on [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72068/45856) today, ouch!

Comment: First off, you only got 1 downvote (most likely from @Paulie_D) so it wasn't that bad. Second off, downvoting isn't "not being nice": it isn't a reflection on you, simply on the question. That can be the content of the question or simply the wording. Finally, no-one has ever said "you aren't smart enough to ask questions here". However, when you join a site, it can be difficult to discover what a good question and everyone will have one question which got downvoted. It's the nature of SE.

Comment: @user00001 Thanks. I have some experience joining new SEs. There were *at least two down votes that came within the span of an hour*, and since the Americas were just starting to wake up and log in with Europe following shortly thereafter, I was concerned about a runaway drive-by down-vote effect. It really happens, especially to OP's with few posts and very low rep, so there is some pressure to feel "protective" in the beginning - perhaps overly so in this case. What increased my concern was the lack of any constructive comments how to improve the question. OK live and learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "offending" part of the question (if you will), which led to my comment, was..

> Did this go anywhere in the plot, or as the entire three-film series continued, did Nancy Pierpan remain a coincidental neighbor and learn the tradecraft from Worricker as time went on?

There is *nothing* in the question which indicates that you have watched all three movies to explain your confusion...indeed, it's easily inferred that you haven't, hence the question I asked.

For that reason, it's attracted downvotes, presumably as "does not show any research"....because you haven't stated one way or another that you have seen all three movies.

---

On the other hand, thanks for turning me on to these movies. I will be watching them and hope to provide an answer...now that you have clarified.

Comment: OK, thanks for the feedback! Every SE is different and often takes some getting used to, luckily we have the metas. I'll try to "find my film voice" here.